# How can I boot using Ansible on an Dell iDRAC9 server from an iso that's located on a remote server?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have this code that what I'm trying to do it's to install CentOS using Ansible on multiple Dell iDRAC9 servers and I'm having 2 issues:

1)If the ISO it's not mounted on the console, then the Attach virtual media task it's not even executed because of the when clause, if the ISO it's mounted then everything it's fine

2)After the ISO it's mounted, the server has not entered automatically into ISO boot menu, and I'm trying to achieve this by the Set boot order task.

Can someone please help me to correct this?

Here's the code:

```
- hosts: Linux_OS_machine
  connection: local
  name: ULP image install
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/env python
    datatype: SetBiosAttributes
    image: "{{ iso_version }}-{{ inventory_hostname }}.iso"

  tasks:
    - name: Check system power state
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        method: GET
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        return_content: yes
      register: system_status

    - name: Power on system if off
      when: system_status.json.PowerState == "Off"
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset/
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        method: POST
        body:
          ResetType: On
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 204
        body_format: json

    - name: Wait for 5 minutes for system to power on
      pause:
        minutes: 5
      when: system_status.json.PowerState == "Off"

    - name: Check if virtual media is mounted
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        method: GET
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        return_content: yes
      register: vm_status

    - name: Unmount virtual media if mounted
      when:
        - vm_status is defined
        - vm_status.json.MediaTypes | default([]) | length > 0
        - vm_status.json.MediaTypes[0] != "NoMedia"
        - vm_status.json.Image == image
        - vm_status.json.ConnectedVia == "VirtualMedia"
        - not (vm_status.json.Status is defined and vm_status.json.Status == "NotConnected")
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD/Actions/VirtualMedia.EjectMedia
        method: POST
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 204
        body_format: json
      register: vm_unmount

    - name: Attach virtual media
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD/Actions/VirtualMedia.InsertMedia
        method: POST
        headers:
          Authorization: Basic {{ (idrac_user + ':' + idrac_pass) | b64encode }}
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 204
        body_format: json
        body:
          Image: ""
      when: vm_status.json.Status == "NotConnected"  


    - name: Set boot order
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Bios/Settings/
        method: PATCH
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: no
        force_basic_auth: yes
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        body_format: json
        body:
          Attributes:
            BootSourceOverrideTarget: Cd
            BootSourceOverrideEnabled: Continuous
            BootSourceOverrideMode: Uefi
            BootSourceOverrideSupported:
              - None
              - Pxe
              - Hdd
              - Cd
              - Floppy
              - Diags
              - BiosSetup
              - Utilities
      register: boot_order



    - name: Reboot the system
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac
          }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset/
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        method: POST
        body:
          ResetType: ForceRestart
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 204
        body_format: json
    - name: Wait for 5 minutes for system to power on
      pause:
        minutes: 5
    - name: Pause for 15 minutes for ULP image to be installed
      pause:
        minutes: 15
    - name: Wait for system to boot up
      wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        delay: 30
        timeout: 900
    - name: Remove custom images from MC Repo host
      file:
        path: /var/opt/ulp_pkg_repo/ulp_pkg_repo/{{ iso_version }}-{{ inventory_hostname
          }}.iso
        state: absent
      delegate_to: "{{ mc_repo_ip }}"
```

The code it's executed fine  but the ISO it's not mounted if no ISO it's mounted on the system, if the ISO it's mounted the everything it's OK.

Comment: Before going further, you probably want to have a look at the dedicated modules: https://github.com/dell/dellemc-openmanage-ansible-modules

Comment: @Zeitounator i can't use dedicated modules unfortunately, I need to rely on redfish calls :(

Comment: Then this is the point where your question definitely becomes off topic on SO. Try https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and see if it's working:

```
- hosts: Linux_OS_machine
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    datatype: SetBiosAttributes

  tasks:
    - name: Check if virtual media is mounted
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        method: GET
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        return_content: yes
      register: vm_status

    - name: Umount virtual media if mounted
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD/Actions/VirtualMedia.EjectMedia"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: json
        status_code: 204
      vars:
        image: "{{ iso_version }}-{{ inventory_hostname }}.iso"
      when:
        - vm_status.json.ConnectedVia == "VirtualMedia"
        - vm_status.json.Status != "NotConnected"
        - vm_status.json.Image == image

    - name: Mount virtual media
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD/Actions/VirtualMedia.InsertMedia"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: False
        status_code: [200, 204]
        body:
          Image: ""
          Oem: {
            "Dell": {
              "BootOnce": "Cd"
            }
          }
        body_format: json
      when:
        - vm_status.json.ConnectedVia == "NotConnected"
        
    - name: Set BIOS boot mode to Legacy
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Bios/Settings"
        method: PATCH
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: False
        status_code: [200, 204]
        body:
          Attributes:
            BootMode: Bios
        body_format: json

    - name: Change boot order to boot from HDD
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1
        method: PATCH
        headers:
          Authorization: Basic {{ (idrac_user + ':' + idrac_pass) | b64encode }}
          Content-Type: application/json
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: [200, 204]
        body_format: json
        body:
          Boot:
            BootSourceOverrideTarget: Hdd
            BootSourceOverrideEnabled: Continuous
            BootSourceOverrideMode: Legacy
            
    - name: Set ISO as primary boot device for installing the ULP
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1
        method: PATCH
        headers:
          Authorization: Basic {{ (idrac_user + ':' + idrac_pass) | b64encode }}
          Content-Type: application/json
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: [200, 204]
        body_format: json
        body:
          Boot:
            BootSourceOverrideTarget: Cd
            BootSourceOverrideEnabled: Once
            BootSourceOverrideMode: Legacy

    - name: Wait for system to power off
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ idrac }}"
        port: 623
        timeout: 300
        state: stopped


    - name: Power on server
      uri:
        url: https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/Actions/ComputerSystem.Reset
        method: POST
        headers:
          Authorization: Basic {{ (idrac_user + ':' + idrac_pass) | b64encode }}
          Content-Type: application/json
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: [200, 204]
        body_format: json
        body:
          ResetType: GracefulRestart

    - name: Display message after restarting system
      debug:
        msg: "Wait for the ULP installation to be completed."


    - name: Wait for ssh
      wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
        timeout: 8000
        delay: 30
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Umount virtual media if mounted, ignore errors if not
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ idrac }}/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1/VirtualMedia/CD/Actions/VirtualMedia.EjectMedia"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ idrac_user }}"
        password: "{{ idrac_pass }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: yes
        body_format: json
        status_code: 204
      vars:
        image: "{{ iso_version }}-{{ inventory_hostname }}.iso"
```

This is what we're using in our environment, I hope it'll help you :)